# How to initialize an iterator to something invalid if the container is not known?

Tags: c++, containers, visitor-pattern

I want to use a visitor given to a more complex function which should inflict changes on a container via the visitor of which is has only general knowledge.
The example is reduced to a minimum. The real visitor has more functions and does not necessarily handle a container at all.

```
class IntersectionHandler{
public:  
  virtual void advance()=0;
  virtual void treatIntersection()=0;
};

class OverlapDisabler: public IntersectionHandler{
private:
  std::vector<Segment>  mEmpty;
  std::vector<Segment>* mpLinesToSearch;
  std::vector<Segment>::iterator mLineIter;

public:
  InsideCollector():mEmpty(),mpLinesToSearch(&mEmpty),mLineIter(mEmpty.end(){}

  void setLineContainer(std::vector<Segment>* lines){
    mpLinesToSearch = lines;
    mLineIter = mpLinesToSearch->begin();                                                            
  }

  void advance(){
    if(mLineIter != mpLinesToSearch->end()) ++mLineIter;
  }
  void treatIntersection(){
    if(mLineIter != mpLinesToSearch->end()) mLineIter->disable();
  }    
};
```

To intitailize the iterator I use a dummy vector, that I must keep as a class member in this case. Usually I would initialise the iterator with some globally invalid value such as 0 for a pointer.

Unfortunately 0 is not a valid value for an iterator with many compilers and also seems a little odd to use. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish what I am trying without resorting to an empty dummy container?

Comment: Iterators do have the limitation of not having the nullptr (or 0 before C++11), universal invalid value.  When I encounter this type of problems, I  pass in the container (as reference) that the the iterator is supposed to be working on as an argument. Then you can set invalid iterator as mycontainer.end().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer**

You can't, there is no value for standard iterators that puts them into an *"invalid state"*.

---

**Proposed solution**

Instead of relying on the value of `mLineIter`, default-initialize `mLineIter` and initialize `mpLinesToSearch` to `nullptr` in the constructor.

This way you will now that `mLineIter` isn't a valid iterator if `mpLinesToSearch` is still `nullptr`.

*SAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION*

```
class OverlapDisabler: public IntersectionHandler{
private:
  std::vector<Segment>* mpLinesToSearch;
  std::vector<Segment>::iterator mLineIter;

public:
  InsideCollector() : mpLinesToSearch (nullptr), mLineIter() { }

  ...

  void advance(){
    if (mpLinesToSearch == nullptr)
      return; // no iterator to increment

    if(mLineIter != mpLinesToSearch->end()) ++mLineIter;
  }

 ...     

  void treatIntersection(){
    if(mpLinesToSearch == nullptr)
      return; // the iterator doesn't refer to any element

    if(mLineIter != mpLinesToSearch->end()) mLineIter->disable();
  }    
};
```

( **Note**: If you are compiling your source as *C++03*, `nullptr` isn't available; if that is the case use `NULL` or `0` to initialize your pointer )

Comment: You can also tell if `mLineIter` is invalid if it compares equal to `iterator()`.  Also, it's usually undefined behavior to advance an uninitialized iterator, so adding an `assert` or `throw` might be in order.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Can you compare against iterator()? So does if(mLineIter != std::vector<Segment>::iterator()) really make sense?

Comment: @MooingDuck **No**, comparing two uninitialized iterators is undefined behavior according to [iterator.requirements.general]p5; *"Iterators can also have singular values that are not associated with any sequence. Results of most expressions are undefined for singular values; the only exceptions are destroying an iterator that holds a singular value, the assignment of an non-singular value to an iterator that holds a singular value, and, for iterators that satisfy the DefaultConstructible requirements, using a value-initialized iterator as the source of a copy or move operation."*

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp: I was also checking the spec and found similar wording: §24.2.5/2 "The domain of == for forward iterators is that of iterators over the same underlying sequence. However, value-initialized iterators may be compared and shall compare equal to other value-initialized iterators of the same type."  Your quote is far more explicit though.

Answer (score 3):

if boost is an option, you may use [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

or since C++17, [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: So you mean an optional iterator? Good Idea!

Answer (score 1):

Some containers seem to have default constructors for their iterators in invalid state. This is true for std::set, std::map and their *multi* equivalents.

Check this out: [onlinegdb example](https://onlinegdb.com/HJ7GWa__H)